# Terminal and non terminal symbols

Tags: design-patterns, interpreter-pattern

I am currently reading about the interpreter pattern and there it says something about Terminal and nonterminal symbols. So I went to wikipedia and read about it. But I still don't understand what a terminal and nonterminal symbol is. Can you give me some examples with programming. I don't want the wikipedia page copy-pasted... I want real world examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every language — be it a human language, computer language, or scientific notation — is made up of symbols. These symbols are the smallest meaningful units of the language, e.g. human languages have words and punctuation; maths has numbers and operators; Java has identifiers, literals, and symbols. These fundamental symbols are the ***terminals***, the smallest parts that you can break statements into.

Theses terminals are strung together to make statements, and languages have specific ways that you can string non-terminals together to convey meaning e.g. in maths, you can join a number, an operand, and another number (e.g. `5` `+` `2`) to make an *operation*, and in Java you can join an identifier, an equals-sign symbol, a number literal, and a semicolon symbol (e.g. `size` `=` `50` `;`) to make an *assignment statement*. These allowed ways of combining terminals are called ***non-terminals***. Non-terminals can be combinations of terminals, other non-terminals, or both.

So basically, terminals are the symbols of a language, while non-terminals are the combinations of those terminals to make expressions and statements. As an example, a simple programming language may have terminals like `if`, `else`, `while`, `+`, `-`, `(`, `)`, `++`, `--`, `'\n'`, `3.14159`, and many more. These terminals can be combined into non-terminals such as:

- Assignment statement
- If statement
- While loop
- Variable declaration
- *and so on*

What the interpreter pattern is that it takes those terminal and non-terminal symbols and defines them as classes or data-types that match the structure of a language. So for terminal symbols like numbers, or identifiers, they could be defined like

```java
abstract class Symbol {
    abstract int evaluate();
}

class Number extends Symbol {
    int value;

    @Override int evaluate() {
        return value;
    }
}

class Identifier extends Symbol {
    String name;

    @Override int evaluate() {
        return getIdentifierValue(name);
    }
}
```

and then non-terminal symbols like if statements or expressions could be defined like

```java
class IfStatement extends Symbol {
    Symbol condition;
    Symbol ifBranch;
    Symbol elseBranch;

    @Override int evaluate() {
        if (condition.evaluate() != 0)
            return ifBranch.evaluate();
        else
            return elseBranch.evaluate();
    }
}

class AddExpression extends Symbol {
    Symbol left;
    Symbol right;

    @Override int evaluate() {
        return left.evaluate() + right.evaluate();
    }
}
```

So you can see, terminals represent the values like numbers, identifiers and strings, and non-terminals represent the expressions and statements built up recursively from those terminals. I'm not that good at explaining theory, but I hope the practical examples here will help you understand.

Comment: so the terminals are the building blocks, while the non terminals are builded constructions?(that can recursively be used as building blocks for other constructions?)

Comment: That's pretty much it.